# Failed to load class for data source: Libsvm in spark ML pyspark/scala

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, mapr, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

When I try to import a libsvm file in pyspark/scala using `"sqlContext.read.format("libsvm").load"`, I get the following error -

> "Failed to load class for data source: Libsvm."

At the same time, if I use `"MLUtils.loadLibSVMFile"` it works perfectly fine. I need to use both `Spark ML` (to get class probabilities) and `MLlib` for an evaluation. Have attached the error screenshot.

This is a MapR cluster. Spark version 1.5.2
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/quYY2.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`libsvm` source format is available since version 1.6 of Spark.

Answer (score 0):

this is probably a version mismatch, the version of libsvm you have in your project may not have that particular API, can you verify the version of libsvm is loaded and then determine if that api is available?

Comment: Thanks Andrew. The function is not available for the version I'm using.

Comment: I don't have the privilege yet!